# Powershell script runs but task scheduler wont run it

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I have a powershell script that runs in ISE but wont run in Task Scheduler. It is a simple powershell script to move a file... I have it set to run at a specific time in task scheduler, but it wont run. When I try to run it manually from task scheduler, it gets stuck on running. Its moving the file to a mapped drive. I have the task scheduler set to run whether the user is logged on or not and with higest priviledges and its also under an admin account... Based upon research, I found articles about the PSDrive cmdlet if you are using mapped drives but I dont know how to incorporate it into my script...Can anyone help me incorporate the PSDrive cmdlet if this is the issue, thanks.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force
$_SourcePath = "C:\lilsis\seniors_allcourses.csv"
$_DestinationPath = "Z:\"
Copy-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath -force
```

[image]

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGXaF.png)

Comment: Most likely the user running the task (DCSS\administrator) does not know about the `"Z:\"` mapping.. Easiest is to use the full UNC path for that

Comment: What do you mean does not know about? I know that the The Z Drive is a mapped drive... The question is how do I get this script to run... Lol. So this UNC format will be recognized by task scheduler?? Why is it that Powershell ISE can recognize the mapped drive fine but task scheduler cant??

Comment: Drive mappings are personal. **you** may have that drive, but another user probably not.

Comment: Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -Force
$_SourcePath = "C:\lilsis\seniors_allcourses.csv"
$_DestinationPath = "\\CLINKONYSYNC\Classlink OneSync"
Copy-item –path $_SourcePath –destination $_DestinationPath -force

Comment: Thank you for your tip about the UNC Path. I have modified the script and Task Scheduler still does not recognize. It runs fine in ISE but not task scheduler...

Comment: This may be the case , but i still dont understand how PS can recognize it but Task Scheduler cannot, but ok. Windows is pathetic. I guess I have no choice but to open a Microsoft ticket for this simple task that Windows cannot handle lol.

Comment: Just replace the Z: mapping with a **full, absolute UNC path** then read about what mappings are and you'll find out that a mapping for you is not something universal for everyone. A Microsoft ticket ...... LOL

Comment: I did replace it if you see the previous message , I included the new code. Its still not working for Task Schedueler. I dont know. After we come up with the resolution I will comment it on here. Was hoping this could be solved through Stack but I guess no one can figure out Windows, maybe the Microsoft employees can lol :P

Comment: Even written like this it doesnt work for Task Sch. Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -scope Process -force
Copy-item –path "C:\lilsis\seniors_allcourses.csv" –Destination "\\CLINKONYSYNC\Classlink OneSync" -force

Comment: What you are not showing is HOW you set it up in the `Actions` tab.  Should be `Path to the executable:` --> `powershell.exe`. Next in the `Parameters` --> `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Path\To\The\Script.ps1"`. You don't need the first line in your script BTW. Also, make sure the user running this task has read/write access to both paths

Comment: I uploaded another photo to show you the actions tab.. cut me a little slack no need for CAPS. I wasnt aware to screenshot every tab sorry... Anyways the Program/Script is set to the path of the file. The "Add Arguments" is set to -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Users\administrator.DCSS\Desktop\LilSisScript.ps1" , and the first line of the script is removed. Task Scheduler is still not running it... Anymore suggestions? Need me to screenshot any more tabs?

Comment: No, the program is `powershell.exe` (the executable that runs the script you give it in the Arguments)

Comment: What do you do? You are a genius. Thank you my friend.

Comment: Glad to have helped